# Как приконнектиться к MySql в локальной сети?

Tags: mysql

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("192.168.3.50", "root", "123", "db_name");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

printf("Host information: %s\n", $mysqli->host_info);

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Connect failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.3.57' (using password: YES)
```

где 192.168.3.57 - мой адрес.

Что может быть не так?

Comment: пароль точно верен?

Comment: да, пароль правильный

Comment: С локальной машины это работает? по localhost

Comment: да, по локалхосту коннект есть

Comment: Пользователь был неверный( все заработало, спасибо.